# Finding the hypercenter of a finite group in GAP

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

I usually find the hypercenter of a finite group by the command

Hypercenter:=Union(UpperCentralSeries(g));

Its look odd, since I take the union of all the $i$th center of $g$ and "Hypercenter" is treated as a set and not as a subgroup. Is there any other way to find the hypercentral of a finite group?

Thanks for any help?

Comment: How about UpperCentralSeries(g)[1] ?

Comment: @DerekHolt This is nice. Can you pose it as an answer so that i can accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Hypercenter := UpperCentralSeries(g)[1];
```